# Can we use configure layout to customize form with document libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I'm able to use configure layout to customize a form for a list.

But no idea how to use the same for a document library? Is it possible?

Since there is no new form link for document libraries is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to use "Configure layout" settings/options for SharePoint document library:

1. Go to your SharePoint document library
2. Select any document inside the library. If not available, add any dummy document for time being.
3. Select **Properties** from top command bar:

   [image]
4. Click on "Edit form" drop down and select "Configure layout":

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. Not sure how i missed it :(

Comment: You're welcome, @naijacoder!